# Z-order for share box is wrong for suspended user

Tags: bug, design, account-suspension, share-this

When user is under suspension tapping on "edit" link below the post body opens the popup message "Account is suspended". If you then tap on the "share" link, share box appears under the popup:

> [image: z-order]

Comment: Suspension means you shouldn't be able to edit anything. Suspension does not mean you shouldn't be able to share the profile. Makes perfect sense - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Nij problem is in the GUI. New window shouldn't appear under another one. It should be on the top.

Comment: Priority window should appear over any other, not be hidden. Seems like intended behaviour and a good one at that.

Comment: @Nij priority here is not a sense. Because sharing doesn't depend from editing.

Comment: Why not just hide edit link for suspended?

Comment: @vp_arth Because we are talking about the share link not the edit link.

Comment: @DavidPostill with no edit link there's will be no windows overlapping. In normal case there is "flag" button too, but it's hidden for suspended user.

Comment: @alexolut Ah. Got it.